# Could TypeScript model this function if it had dependent types?

Tags: typescript, dependent-type

Say I have a TypeScript type for Vehicles that I'm modeling as the union of two interfaces. I also have a visitor interface for working with vehicles:

```
interface Car { type: 'car'; make: string; model: string; }
interface Bicycle { type: 'bicycle'; brand: string; numGears: number; }

type Vehicle = Car | Bicycle;

interface VehicleVisitor {
  car: (v: Car) => void;
  bicycle: (v: Bicycle) => void;
}

// or:
// type VehicleVisitor = { [T in Vehicle['type']]: (v: Extract<Vehicle, {type: T}>) => void; };
```

Now I want to write the function that applies a visitor to a vehicle:

```
function visitVehicle(vehicle: Vehicle, visitor: VehicleVisitor) {
  visitor[vehicle.type](vehicle);
  //                    ~~~~~~~
  // Argument of type 'Vehicle' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  //   The intersection 'Car & Bicycle' was reduced to 'never' because property
  //   'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
}
```

TypeScript knows that `vehicle.type` is `"car" | "bicycle"`, so `visitor[vehicle.type]` is `(v: Car) => void | (v: Bicycle) => void`. To call that safely, you'd need a value in `Car & Bicycle`, i.e. `never`, hence the error.

But the call *is* safe. You can convince TypeScript of it by spelling things out a little more:

```
function visitVehicleVerbose(vehicle: Vehicle, visitor: VehicleVisitor) {
  if (vehicle.type === 'car') {
    visitor[vehicle.type](vehicle);  // ok
  } else {
    visitor[vehicle.type](vehicle);  // also ok
  }
}
```

This works because TypeScript is able to narrow the type of `vehicle` to `Car` in the first branch and `Bicycle` in the second. But the code is exactly the same in both branches, so the `if` statement isn't necessary.

I've been trying to understand what dependent types are, and [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) makes me think that this situation is at least in the ballpark.

Is this the sort of problem that dependent types solve? Or is this something different entirely? Or maybe it's just a gap in TypeScript's type checker that other languages can handle? Or maybe this code isn't correct and there's a case I'm not thinking of.

(In the [real code](https://github.com/danvk/gravlax/blob/07cac05202b23e58677bd836091e602b1390e0f8/src/ast.ts#L128-L132) that inspired this, I just wrote `vehicle as never` to work around this.)

Comment: It's impossible to say whether introduction of dependent types would change things significantly, but you don't need them: I've been referring to the issue you're running into "correlated unions" as described in [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and the officially supported approach is to refactor to generics in the particular way described in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). For your example that looks like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/m0OZPN). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?